# Separate taskbar icons for Chrome and Chrome Incognito

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar, shortcuts

**How can I create separate taskbar icons in Windows 7 for Google Chrome and Google Chrome's incognito mode?**

I tried several solutions so far with no success.

---

Of course I tried doing one shortcut for `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito` and one for `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` but they always end with sharing the same element in the Windows taskbar.

I also tried a trick: duplicate `chrome.exe` into `chrome2.exe` and have these shortcuts: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome2.exe"` , but this didn't work as well: it works temporarily, but after a reboot, it seems that both taskbar icons have merged into one.

Comment: Did you set different icons for the two short-cuts? I have done this for other programs (eg `cmd` started normally and as administrator), and it works fine.

Comment: This isn't *precisely* what you are after, but are you aware that simply right-clicking the Chrome icon in your taskbar offers you incognito mode as a context menu option?

Comment: Yes @BradleyEvans, I already use that, but now I'm looking for a single-click solution - two nice separate taskbar icons :)

Comment: The "pinned shortcuts" icons are stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`. You might try adding a new `*.lnk` file there that has the properties you require, it may be that the `.lnk` files kept on being generated with the same name and overriding each other.

Comment: How chrome profiles have separated icons?

Answer (score 5):

Windows *really* doesn't want to give you full access to these shortcuts (and they have [good reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673/)).  The problem is that you can't pin 2 of the same application.  But what if we pin a second application to launch the first?

1. Pin `Google Chrome` to the taskbar as you would normally.
2. Pin the `Command Prompt` to your taskbar as well.
3. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog, and enter the following location:
   `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
4. Edit the properties of the `Command Prompt` shortcut and change the Target to:
   `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito`

   > [CMD /C](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates *but it won't terminate until after the command has completed.*
   >   [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) can initiate a process *without* waiting for it to complete
5. Change the icon to the incognito icon (browse for the Chrome executable).
6. On the General tab, change the shortcut name to "Chrome Incognito" or similar.
   (You need to restart the explorer process or reboot for the icon to change).
7. On the Shortcut tab, change the Run setting to `Minimized`.

*Note: since Chrome running in incognito mode is still Chrome, it appears under the original Chrome icon, not the incognito one.*

Surprisingly I'm now allowed to pin the command prompt to the taskbar again.  I really did not expect that to work, since I already pinned it.

All if this is so difficult because you can't simply put any shortcut you want into the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` folder.  From my searching, [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1133406) shows it best why.  The shortcut data is written in the registry in binary.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it displays a short ( < 0.5 second) cmd.exe window that immediately disappears after Chrome is launched. Not a big deal, but such things can be annoying ;)

Comment: Added step 7, seems to work pretty well.

Comment: It was working nice @Ian, except that now every regular `cmd.exe` window ... is associated to the Chrome Incognito icon on taskbar, arghh !

Comment: I expected that to happen, but I tested it and it doesn't do that for me.  Are you able to pin the Command Prompt to the taskbar, or does it show the `Unpin` option?

Comment: I just went through it again step-by-step, and it works fine for me.  I'm running Win7 Home Premium SP1.  What you got?

Comment: Win7 Pro. In fact when starting a new `cmd` from Start menu, it has a separate icon (expected behaviour). But when I do SHIFT + RIGHT click in the white empty part of a folder in Explorer, and I do "Open command window here", then it shares the same icon as Chrome incognito (non expected behaviour).

Comment: Confirmed, same for me.  I don't think that's avoidable with this solution.

Comment: Maybe we could copy `cmd.exe` into `cmd2.exe` @Ian, what do you think? Does this work? (I don't have computer to try right now)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to have two separate installations of Chrome, one [Chrome stable](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) and another [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html). You can set the `--incognito` flag to any one of them and they should work fine.

Comment: Good idea, but this would need to reinstall the extensions twice, etc.

Comment: You can log into both Chrome installations using the same Google account and it should install the same extensions for both installations (if extension sync is enabled, which is the default behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I added to the taskbar an icon for Chrome with incognito that looks
like this:
[image: image1]

1. Position to the Chrome folder, usually at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`
2. Right-click the file `chrome.exe` and choose `Send to -> Desktop (create shortcut)`
3. This will create a desktop icon for Chrome
4. Right-click the icon and choose `Properties`
5. In the Properties dialog that opens, in the Target box append `--incognito`
6. Still in the dialog, click `Change Icon ...`
7. Click another icon than the default and then click OK
   [image: image2]
8. You could also optionally click on the General tab and change the shortcut text
9. Click OK
10. Right-click the desktop icon and choose `Pin to taskbar`
11. You now have the taskbar icon with the chosen icon image and where the
    popup text when hovering with the cursor is as set in step 8 above.
    You may also now delete the desktop icon.

Comment: It works during a few minutes/hours/days. And then eventually one of the 2 icons disappears again (really!). Maybe after one reboot or two.
I remembered I already tried this weeks ago. And yes, again, disappeared!

Comment: I think this happens due to updates (that automatically happen in the background)

Comment: Oh maybe @ChiragBhatia-chirag64. How to totally disable such updates?

Comment: That's not something I would suggest you do actually, but if you're keen, check out [these steps](http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update) to disable auto-updates of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hi! I know is too late. I was trying to do the same in Windows 10's taskbar. And i've found a simple solution:

1. Enter chrome in normal mode (no incognito) and go to any website
2. Create a shortcut to that website, it'll appear on your desktop
3. Right-click it and then go to propeties
4. In destiny erase all from right to left until you get to proxy.exe"
5. Write in front of proxy.exe" the next: -incognito
6. Change the icon if you want and then click accept or aply or both wathever
7. Drag and drop the shortcut on taskbar, it will be linked and it will stay there forever no matter if you reboot the system.

This works because when Chrome installs a shortcut it actually installs it, i mean, you can find it on programs in control panel, as you can see below.

[How the shortcut should be edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDY4N.png)

[The web that I used's shortcut "installed" as an independent program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwEpt.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Make a shortcut to `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --incognito"`.** Bring the incognito icon from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` if you want to (<kbd>Change Icon</kbd>). Pin it to the taskbar.

This way, you can have the three different shortcuts on your taskbar.

- *Windows PowerShell*
- *Chrome*
- ***Chrome (incognito)***