# Deleted pinned taskbar items reappear after boot

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Title says it all - this is driving me nuts. After reboot, Outlook and IE are pinned to the taskbar even though I explicitly removed them.

Following [this resource](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/65cwrg/windows_10_taskbar_pinned_items_return_every/) on Reddit, and [Where is the list of pinned start menu and taskbar items stored in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7) on SU, I scoured all Taskbar folders for every user and the registry under taskband - nothing.

I'll note the public and default users have no such folder, and the rest do not have links to IE or outlook (e.g. `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`).

In the Reddit post I linked to the solution alludes that `C:\ProgramData` may help, but I found nothing.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the icon and pressing "Unpin from taskbar"?

Comment: Do you have anything else pinned to the taskbar? Have you tried removing any other taskbar items? Do they stay removed?

Comment: @freginold Yes to both with an *. I removed the search icon, and now I removed something I added - both seem wo stay removed on restart. IE was on from the beginning, but outlook I added (I think, mistakenly) and now keeps coming back.