# Can I create second taskbar shortcut list in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I'm web developer.
My hobby is music.

It would be nice if I can fast switch between these two content of taskbar (see this two screens):
[Dev Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOnQP.png)
[Sound Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMecB.png)

Presence of unused shortcuts distracts me.

Two operation system accounts is not good option for me:
I don't want waste time to configure and maintain second account again and again.

The best option is the ability to quickly change shortcut list on taskbar.

Maybe I need to substitute some file or directory.
Or maybe there is some software that adds this ability.

Answer (score 1):

The pinned apps in the taskbar are [in the *User*'s *Roaming* AppData](https://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7):

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, i.e.

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

Just create a batch file to rename two folders with the correct shortcuts. Of course, it requires three steps: rename Folder A to temp, Folder B to Folder A, and temp to Folder B. You might also need to kill and restart Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

A low-tech solution:

1. Group your shortcuts, so the development-related ones are at one end,
   the sound related ones are at the other end,
   and the ones that you want access to all the time are between them.
2. Put a "sticky note" or other opaque adhesive material over the ones
   that you don't want to see. 
   You can move that back and forth in less time than it takes
   to do anything on the computer.